# Is there a kernel option to allow a userspace app discovering custom USB devices on the host?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, usb-device, buildroot

Consider a minimalist, buildroot-based Linux image on some 1-PCB computer with a USB host port.

Then there is another small computer: a Raspberry Pi Compute Module "CM3", the only connection between the two is USB.
When the CM3 has a Linux running on it, it acts as a ethernet gadget for communication.

But when the CM3 needs to be flashed, an input pin on it, toggled by the buildroot machine, tells it "boot mode", and it will become a custom USB device "BCM2710 Boot".
The Raspi folks then offer a *userspace* program, [usbboot aka *rpiboot*](https://github.com/raspberrypi/usbboot/blob/master/main.c#L210), to find the device *via VID* and upload a small image turning it into a mass storage device.

When I try this, plugging the CM3 USB into a "normal" RaspberryPi's host USB port, I see this with *dmesg*:

```
[16689.527482] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[16689.657906] usb 1-1.3: config index 0 descriptor too short (expected 55, got 32)
[16689.658302] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=2764, bcdDevice= 0.00
[16689.658319] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[16689.658335] usb 1-1.3: Product: BCM2710 Boot
[16689.658350] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Broadcom
```

*Rpiboot* does then find the device and sends over that spepcial image mentioned. So that works.

But when I plug it into my buildroot machine instead, I only see this:

```
[  597.725309] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci-hcd
[  601.965304] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci-hcd
```

So it appears to see that there is some USB thing new, but won't go further.
And *rpiboot* waits forever instead of finding it like on the Raspi-host.
So it seems there are one or more Linux kernel config options which are not enabled in my buildroot image, which prevents this from working. I got this idea because initially, all the ethernet gadget stuff also did not work and I had to go and enable CDCETHER and some other options - but I have no idea what to look for with this non-standard device here. There are a lot of not-enabled CONFIG_USB_* options that seem to pertain to specific devices, but nothing like "custom" or such.

**What is/are the corresponding option(s)?**

---

Added: a view of sorted and line-matched (where same options) excerpts of both kernel configurations: I removed everything that's the same setting on both sides, drivers of specific devices, or nothing to do with USB, to shrink the listing by a fair amount.
I went through short descriptons of these kernel options on https://cateee.net/, and so far saw nothing that seemed to fit the bill - but it's not said I didn't overlook or misinterpret something...

```
configRaspi4-Raspbian                           configBuildrootDevice
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CONFIG_HISI_HIKEY_USB is not set                
CONFIG_MEDIA_USB_SUPPORT=y                      
CONFIG_NOP_USB_XCEIV=y                          CONFIG_NOP_USB_XCEIV is not set
CONFIG_USB_ACM=m                                CONFIG_USB_ACM=y
CONFIG_USB_ADUTUX=m                             CONFIG_USB_ADUTUX is not set
CONFIG_USB_AIRSPY is not set                    
CONFIG_USB_AN2720=y                             
CONFIG_USB_ARMLINUX=y                           
CONFIG_USB_ATM=m                                
CONFIG_USB_BELKIN=y                             
CONFIG_USB_CDC_COMPOSITE=m                      CONFIG_USB_CDC_COMPOSITE is not set
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_ACM=y                       CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_ACM is not set
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_ECM_SUBSET=y                
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_ECM=y                       CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_ECM is not set
                                                CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_ECM_SUBSET is not set
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_F_FS=y                      CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_F_FS is not set
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_F_HID=y                     CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_F_HID is not set
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_F_LB_SS=y                   CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_F_LB_SS is not set
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_F_UAC2=y                    
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_NCM=y                       CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_NCM is not set
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_OBEX=y                      CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_OBEX is not set
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_RNDIS=y                     CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_RNDIS is not set
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_SERIAL=y                    CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_SERIAL is not set
CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS=m                           CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS=y
CONFIG_USB_DEFAULT_PERSIST=y                    CONFIG_USB_DEFAULT_PERSIST is not set
CONFIG_USB_DWC2_DEBUG is not set                
CONFIG_USB_DWC2_DUAL_ROLE=y                     
CONFIG_USB_DWC2_HOST is not set                 
CONFIG_USB_DWC2_PCI is not set                  
CONFIG_USB_DWC2_PERIPHERAL is not set           
CONFIG_USB_DWC2_TRACK_MISSED_SOFS is not set    
CONFIG_USB_DWC2=m                               CONFIG_USB_DWC2 is not set
                                                CONFIG_USB_DWC3_DUAL_ROLE=y
                                                CONFIG_USB_DWC3_GADGET is not set
                                                CONFIG_USB_DWC3_HAPS=y
                                                CONFIG_USB_DWC3_HOST is not set
                                                CONFIG_USB_DWC3_OF_SIMPLE=y
                                                CONFIG_USB_DWC3_OTG is not set
CONFIG_USB_DWC3 is not set                      CONFIG_USB_DWC3=y
CONFIG_USB_DWCOTG=y                             
CONFIG_USB_ETH_EEM is not set                   CONFIG_USB_ETH_EEM=y
CONFIG_USB_ETH=m                                CONFIG_USB_ETH=y
CONFIG_USB_EZUSB_FX2=m                          CONFIG_USB_EZUSB_FX2 is not set
CONFIG_USB_F_ACM=m                              
CONFIG_USB_F_ECM=m                              CONFIG_USB_F_ECM=y
CONFIG_USB_F_EEM=m                              CONFIG_USB_F_EEM=y
CONFIG_USB_F_FS=m                               
CONFIG_USB_F_HID=m                              
CONFIG_USB_F_MASS_STORAGE=m                     CONFIG_USB_F_MASS_STORAGE=y
CONFIG_USB_F_NCM=m                              
CONFIG_USB_F_OBEX=m                             
CONFIG_USB_F_RNDIS=m                            CONFIG_USB_F_RNDIS=y
CONFIG_USB_F_SERIAL=m                           
CONFIG_USB_F_SS_LB=m                            
CONFIG_USB_F_SUBSET=m                           CONFIG_USB_F_SUBSET=y
CONFIG_USB_F_UAC2=m                             
CONFIG_USB_FEW_INIT_RETRIES is not set          
CONFIG_USB_G_ACM_MS=m                           CONFIG_USB_G_ACM_MS is not set
CONFIG_USB_G_HID=m                              CONFIG_USB_G_HID is not set
CONFIG_USB_G_MULTI_CDC is not set               
CONFIG_USB_G_MULTI_RNDIS=y                      
CONFIG_USB_G_MULTI=m                            CONFIG_USB_G_MULTI is not set
CONFIG_USB_G_SERIAL=m                           CONFIG_USB_G_SERIAL is not set
CONFIG_USB_GADGETFS=m                           CONFIG_USB_GADGETFS is not set
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA=m                              
CONFIG_USB_HIDDEV=y                             CONFIG_USB_HIDDEV is not set
CONFIG_USB_HSO=m                                
CONFIG_USB_LD=m                                 CONFIG_USB_LD is not set
CONFIG_USB_LIBCOMPOSITE=m                       CONFIG_USB_LIBCOMPOSITE=y
CONFIG_USB_MASS_STORAGE=m                       CONFIG_USB_MASS_STORAGE is not set
CONFIG_USB_MON=m                                CONFIG_USB_MON is not set
CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_EEM=m                        CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_EEM=y
CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_MBIM=m                       CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_MBIM is not set
CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_NCM=m                        CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_NCM is not set
CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET_ENABLE=m              
CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET=m                     CONFIG_USB_NET_CDC_SUBSET is not set
CONFIG_USB_NET_CDCETHER=m                       CONFIG_USB_NET_CDCETHER=y
CONFIG_USB_NET_RNDIS_HOST=m                     CONFIG_USB_NET_RNDIS_HOST is not set
CONFIG_USB_NET_RNDIS_WLAN=m                     
                                                CONFIG_USB_OTG_BLACKLIST_HUB is not set
                                                CONFIG_USB_OTG_FSM=y
                                                CONFIG_USB_OTG_WHITELIST is not set
CONFIG_USB_OTG is not set                       CONFIG_USB_OTG=y
CONFIG_USB_OTG_DISABLE_EXTERNAL_HUB is not set  
CONFIG_USB_OTG_PRODUCTLIST is not set           
CONFIG_USB_PWC=m                                
CONFIG_USB_RAW_GADGET is not set                
CONFIG_USB_ROLE_SWITCH=m                        CONFIG_USB_ROLE_SWITCH is not set
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL=m                             CONFIG_USB_SERIAL is not set
CONFIG_USB_SEVSEG=m                             CONFIG_USB_SEVSEG is not set
CONFIG_USB_TEST=m                               CONFIG_USB_TEST is not set
CONFIG_USB_TMC=m                                CONFIG_USB_TMC is not set
CONFIG_USB_U_ETHER=m                            CONFIG_USB_U_ETHER=y
CONFIG_USB_U_SERIAL=m                           
                                                CONFIG_USB_WUSB_CBAF is not set
CONFIG_USB_ZERO=m                               CONFIG_USB_ZERO is not set
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there is no special option needed.

Rpiboot using libusb does, via libusb, by default, require udev to run, which it doesn't, on the host system. It does not complain when you run it on a system without udev, though ... I was fooled by that, as I recently compiled "lsusb" (usbtools) as the BusyBox implementation is lacking, and it crashed on the host system, comlpaining about udev related stuff missing.

After compiling libusb myself, configuring it with "--disable-udev" before, and using that to build rpiboot, that then works.